# Using Router QoS to Prioritize Traffic

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, home-networking

I have an Old Tp-link router which provides these options for QoS i wanted to know if it is possible to prioritize my pc traffic connected through Lan port over all Wifi traffic and if i can do that how should i configure it QOS TD-W8901N
[image]

Comment: What model TP-Link?

Comment: Form the settings it looks like the router can't just use Layer 1 (physical ports) to prioritize traffic unless all of the other Rule-Fields are optional.

Comment: @MarkScheck TD-W8901N

Comment: @Albin how about setting my pc IP and MAC for source ?

Comment: If you want to configure each client separately I guess it would work.